# Cannot pull a newly created empty docker repo: repository not found

Tags: docker, dockerhub

`$ sudo docker pull d33tah/afl-sid
Trying to pull repository docker.io/d33tah/afl-sid ... failed
FATA[0002] Repository not found`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure this repo exists on the hub? I searched for it and didn't come up with any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to [tag and push](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_six/) the repo first.